# How to change pose of armature of a gltf file when the mesh is deformed?

Tags: python, mesh, armature, blender-internal-render-engine, pose-mode

I load a gltf file by pygltf and deform the vertices of gltf mesh by using a nonrigid method. when I export the gltf file, the mesh is deformed but the armature position is not changed.
I am looking for a method to change pose of armature of a gltf file when the mesh is deformed.